# Powershell getting json file with array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make script for auto add zabbix hosts

I have file like this:

```
[
    {
        "host": "somehost",
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "host": "someotherhost",
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "1",
                "groupid": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I read it with
`$Hosts = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot/hosts.json`

And it reads correctly, but if i try to convert it from Json: `$Hosts = $Hosts | ConvertFrom-Json`
it only gets last groupid in array:

```
host          groups         
----          ------         
somehost      {@{groupid=1}}
someotherhost {@{groupid=2}}
```

And i can't figure out how to get all groupid's

I can change json file if it helps

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't support JSON objects with duplicate keys - `"groupid":"2"` basically ends up overwriting the sibling entry `"groupid":"1"` for this reason.

Comment: you probably wanted `[{ "groupid": "1" }, { "groupid": "2" }]`. an array of objects instead of an array with a single object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't support duplicate keys and ends up overwriting the first value with the second one.

According to [Zabbix' API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/host/create), the `groups` property should contain a list of host group *objects*, each with a `groupid` property, so your JSON document should probably look like this instead:

```
[
    {
        "host": "somehost",
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "host": "someotherhost",
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "1",
            },
            {
                "groupid": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```